# How to build browser version in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

How to build browser version using Ionic 4. When I tried to build using ***ionic cordova build browser --prod*** and uploaded ***platforms/browser/www*** files on server and tried to run in browser it’s not showing anything(webpage is blank) and getting below error in devtools.

[image]

Can anyone please help me on the same?

Comment: What error do you see in the browser's devtools console output?

Comment: @Nikola I have edited my question.

Comment: Try ng build --prod

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Thanks for suggestion. I have tried with ng build --prod but still getting same error.

Comment: Then it might be because of some other issue.

Comment: I haven't modified anything in index.html. Ionic serve is working fine but browser build is giving this error.

Comment: might be issue with base href. please check what is the value of <base href="./"> in index.html

Comment: base href is defined as <base href="/" /> in index.html

Comment: base href is most certainly the problem, you need to make sure that it is the path of the public url where the above mentioned files are accessible

Answer (score 4):

Hi I also had this problem with my vuejs apps and it also happened with the new ionic 4 production build.
It looks like these system assume that you are going to drop the "dist" or "www" files in the home directory of your web server like in my case I was using xampp server. But we usally put these files in a sub directory like htdocs/app2.
So for this to work you need to change the `<base href="/" />` in ionic 4 to `<base href="/app2/" />` or what ever your app is. In vue js it's almost the same thing. but you can manually add "/app2" to the index.html file's scripts.
That worked for me; you can try it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to deploy the app in the server in a custom folder then you need to change the `<base href="/" /> to <base href="/custom_folder_name/" />` in the index.html file in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this change in `index.html` base.

**Before:** `href="/" />`
**After:** `<base href="./"`

Answer (score 0):

it changed in the last version. This works for me:
ionic build --prod --public-url=/app/

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, my solution was to upgrade xampp version to latest.

Answer (score -2):

Try ionic build --prod.. The www folder has everything you need for a website.

Comment: I have tried with ionic build --prod and used www folder files also but getting same error.